# Product not showing after adding related products in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to know how the related products functionality works in Magento 2 
especially.

For eg: I have a **product1** for which I add related products, say **product 2,3,4,5**

Doubt is:

1) Why is this **product1** not visible in frontend search after i add related products to it. (If i remove the related prods added to it, then it is displaying)

2) After adding the related products, the related **products 2,3,4,5** should display in the product details page(ie when i click on a **product1**)
Nothing is showing in details page.

I have cleared reindex, cache after saving the products, all 1,2,3,4,5 products are in stock, enabled, no logs.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I've just identified a similar issue with Magento 2.1.3. When we add related products from different attribute sets we're unable to update the given products inventory. Our current workaround is to disable the EAV cache. We've yet to test if upgrading will resolve this though.